# What force moves electrons through a conductor that is rotating in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, conductors

Is it the magnetic force ( F= qv +B ) or the electromagnetic force (F= q(E+vxB) that acts on the electrons of a conductor that is moving in a magnetic field?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about conductors moving in a magnetic field, or are you asking about conductors in a circuit at rest, in the presence of no magnetic field?

Answer (score 0):

Let’s focus on force. Electric current in a wire is cause by net motion of electrons in the wire. The electrons move (in net, overall) due to the fundamental force known as electromagnetism, specifically the electrostatic attraction or repulsion between charged particles. That is the basis for electric fields and electric potential; those are just ways of characterizing and analyzing this attractive and/or repulsive force between charged particles/objects. In the simple situation you describe in your question, magnetism is not part of it. (Although in your answer to your own question, which was never really a question but a point to make, there is a situation where magnetism generates the current)

Coulomb’s law:

> |Force| = k_e (|q1 q2|) / r^2

is the magnitude, and the direction is along a line between them, attractive if q1 and q2 have opposite sign. The constant k_e is called Coulomb's constant and is equal to 1/4πε0 ,  where ε0 is the electric constant; k_e = 8.988×109 N⋅m2⋅C−2.

From wikipedia
“Electromagnetism is the force that acts between electrically charged particles. This phenomenon includes the electrostatic force acting between charged particles at rest, and the combined effect of electric and magnetic forces acting between charged particles moving relative to each other.”

Current flows parallel to the electric field, so even though net charge is moving, it is the former of the above two (electrical not magnetic) that does it. You need *orthogonal* (perpendicular) net motion of charges for magnetism to be involved.

Comment: I am sorry it doesn't answer my question.  What do you think about the right hand rule?  The rule that describes a current carrying conductor moving across a mangetic field. What is that force that the thumb represents?  The force acting on the conductor itself as in a mtor in your drill?   And is  a generator the reverse of the motor?  Instead of current in the wire, you are moving the conductor itself?  I don't think I made my point clear in the post nor here.  Because  I just repeated myself.

Comment: No problem. Will help if can. This is what i answered:
“So is the cause of current in conductors due to magnetic force or electromotive force?” Also the title is “what force moves electrons through a conductor?”  The right hand rule gives the magnetic field caused by moving charges, moving charges such as current in a wire. But you seem to be asking what makes charges (like electrons) move in a conductor (?)

Comment: I didn't want to do this but well it is the only way.  It is to make comments on your main comment.  Since I am allowed only so many characters I have to split it up.  First:  "Electric current in a wire is cause by electrons moving in the wire".  This is false.   Electric current is not caused by electrons moving in a wire.   Electrons moving in a wire is electric current.  Big difference.  So it is not the cause of it.  It is like saying walking is caused by someone walking.   Not good.

Comment: Electric current is not **equivalent to** electrons moving the length of the wire. Electric current IS **caused by** electrons moving in a wire (“diffusion of free electrons” is a type of “electrons moving” which causes electric current).

Comment: Quoting your from you quoting it from wikipedia:  " The electrons move due to the fundamental force known as electromagnetism".  And how this electromagnetism is a combined effect between moving charged particle.   Do you actually see that it is not the cause of current but electromagnetism being an effect of moving charges.   You did not read wikipedia correctly. Right?

Comment: Now lets put it to the test:   If electromagnetism was the cause of current, then why on earth when I have a coil of wires in my hand it shows no current and I don't get killed on the spot?

Comment: There is electromagnetic forces involved in an atom itself since electrons and protons are always moving indeed and in all the atoms that make the copper wire but such movement does not make for so called electric current.  It does not make electricity.  Does it?

Comment: Just keep reading:   Electric current emerges when the free electrons are in the conduction band moving in sync.   This conduction band forming is not caused by EM field.    Read the fine lines......    but they don't make it clear.  So there you have it.

Comment: So try again.   What causes the electrons from the valence to move into the conduction band?

Comment: By the way you also read me wrong.  Nowhere did I say that electric current is the same as electrons moving the length of the wire.   Plus you are also wrong and the source you got that from is also wrong.  I=q/t.  That is the formula.  Nowhere there is mention of distance whatsover.  Look at that formual clearly. I is current. q is the number of charges.  t is time in seconds.  Therefore current is moving charges per unit of time.  That is charges moving at single spot in one second.

Comment: Why discuss senses of “cause”?, proximate cause etc. A field in a conductor makes free electrons diffuse and migrate a bit, and that happens along the wire, which transfers charge from one end to the other (transfers charge in that we can change the potential of something or power something). I say that is acceptably summarized as “moving electrons cause current”. You even wrote: “Electric current emerges when the free electrons are in the conduction band **moving** in sync.” So ‘current emerges when electrons move’ <-> ‘electrons moving causes current’ by some notions fo causality.

Comment: Hey sport.  Electrons moving does not make for electric current. If it did, a dead copper wire will zap you.  Kapeesh?

Comment: I didnt think that you said electric current is electrons moving the length of a wire. Just wanted to make sure you knew I wasnt claiming that when saying “moving electrons cause current”. Also, did you ever really have a question for us? Or just wanted to tell something? In asking cuz not sure

Comment: No Al Brown, I don't have a question for you.  That much is certain. I will answer it myself.

Comment: “A caused B” does not mean “anytime you have A you have B”. Example: “Bobs inattention caused him to trip” does not mean “Every time Bob is inattentive he will trip”.  Similarly, “current is caused by moving current” does not mean “everytime electrons move there is current”. It’s a particular type of moving electrons, net migration to be specific.

Comment: Read my answer and you can thank me for it later.

Comment: Ok Iooked again. Answer : **Not magnetism**. “Electromagnetism is the force acting between electrically charged particles. This phenomenon includes the electrostatic force acting between charged particles at rest, and electric and magnetic forces acting between charged particles moving relative to each other.”

Current flows parallel to the electric field, so even though net current is moving, it is the former of the above two (electrical not magnetic) that does it. If you wanna call that “electromotive” thats fine. But you need orthogonal (perpendicular) motion for magnetism to be involved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128032/discussion-between-ali-and-al-brown).

Answer (score 0):

The force doing work on electrons in a conductor is always an electric force $\vec{F}=q\vec{E}$.  Magnetic forces can do no work since $\vec{F}=q(\vec{v}\times\vec{B})$ is always perpendicular to the velocity $\vec{v}$.

One thing to remember is that EMF is calculated at one particular instant, and is NOT the same as the work done on a physical charge as it moves through the conductor.  To calculate the EMF, you take a snapshot of the situation, compute the integral $\varepsilon = \oint{\vec{f}\cdot d\vec{r}}$, where $\vec{f}=\vec{F}/q$ is the "force per unit charge" on the electron *at that instant in time*. Don't think of this as a work integral, because to calculate the work, you need information about the actual motion of the electrons and the forces that act on them *as they move*.  You don't use that information to compute the EMF. In practice, for most situations you can think of $\vec{f}$ as and electric field $\vec{E}$, which is comprised of two contributions:

(1) a conservative part $\vec{E}_c$ which satisfies $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{E}_c=0$, or equivalently (by Stokes theorem) $\oint{\vec{E}_{c}\cdot d\vec{r}}=0$.

(2) a nonconservative part $\vec{E}_{nc}$ which has nonzero curl: $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{E}_{nc} \ne 0$. The nonconservative electric field in a generator arises due to a time-dependent magnetic field (in the rest frame of the conducting electron.)  It has $\oint{\vec{E}_{nc}\cdot d\vec{r}}\ne 0$ and leads to an EMF.

Comment: That is my point.  Although they define emf as work done on charge, never mind that some say it is not a force either, while its measurement is in terms of work.   It is qBL. It is just the number of chargs with respect to time and magnetic field flux.  And magnetic force is again the same except it refers to the force per unit of charge with respect to time and strength of the field.   The force being orthogonal doesn't do the work.  Voltage is induced by "induction".  Energy moves at far greater velocity than charges.....but that is another story.

Comment: And for the life me I still don't know how energy moves in electrical system.   I can only assume and use the term near-field propagation..

Comment: By the time frame of non-conducting electrons, do you mean the electrons that are not yet in the conduction band?  So it is viewing the conduction band electrons as moving and dissapating heat or?  And by conservative E do you mean to say that charges want to even out and remove potential difference caused by all the stuff we did to them, messing with them, applying energy?

Comment: Editing:  By the rest frame of the electrons you mean the electrons which are not yet moving in the conduction band seeing the electrons moving in the conduction band ?

Comment: I'm not taking any quantum mechanics into account here, so no conduction band or fermi level comes into play in my explanation.  By "rest frame" of the electron, I just mean the reference frame co-moving with the charge. Are you familiar with the idea that magnetic fields and electric fields transform into each other under Lorentz transformation?

Comment: Also, the "conservative" $\vec{E}$ is always static, while the nonconservative $\vec{E}$ is due to time-dependent fields.

Comment: Quantumwave.   I must tell you, there is more involved than I can wrap it in my head at the moment.   The whole question of how, where and the direction of electric energy propagate from the source to the load in transmission line is way more than I bargained for.  No wonder nobody could answer this, the way I was expecting.  It is damn complicated. I mean for me.   I get some of it but the fine details, it hurts my head at the moment.   :-)   https://cds.cern.ch/record/1400571/files/p15.pdf

Comment: I sort of understand how one field can transform into the other, not from Mr. Lorentz but just by observing it in oscillating circuits.   Also from the perspective of relativity I would think.